# the copied database is empty when I copy it from assets folder

Tags: android, database, null, copy, assets

I am new in android programming, I blend some pieces of codes to write what I need. I need to copy a database from assets folder to the internal storage and get some of its contents according to a given ID, However, when I copy the database, the getContent() method returns null which cause some problems, Also, there is an error in SQliteDataBase.openDatabase method at Checkdatabase(). I will be appreciated if someone guide me in this issue. here are my codes:

MyActivity class:

```
    package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
       final DataBaseHelper db= new DataBaseHelper(this);
       final String TAG = "my log in myActivity";

       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               try
               {
                   db.createDataBase();
                   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"copy database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   //db.copyDataBase();
               }
               catch (IOException io)
               {
                   throw new Error("Unable to create database");
               }

               try {
                   db.openDataBase();
                   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"database opened " + db.getContact(1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               } catch (SQLException e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                   Log.d(TAG,"Error"+e);
               }



              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"go to get content",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Contacts contacts = db.getContact(1);
              Log.d(TAG,"log");
              if(contacts == null){
                  Log.d(TAG,"null");
              }
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"value is: " + contacts.getContent(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              //txt.setText(String.valueOf(contacts.getContent()));
           }
       });

    }
 }
```

DatabaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.test;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "DataBase.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "learning";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
    private static final String KEY_ABOUT = "content";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "definition";
    private static final String KEY_FILENAME = "file";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+"com.example.test"       +"/databases/";
    final String TAG = "mylog";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
          //boolean  dbExist = false;
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            //db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("Quran",null);
           // Toast.makeText(myContext,"The empty database address is: " + db.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"the database is "+ db);
            //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS learning(ID INT, CODE INT, CONTENT VARCHAR,DEFINITION VARCHAR,FILE VARCHAR)");
            try {
                Toast.makeText(myContext,"going to copy data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                copyDataBase();
                if (db.isOpen()){
                    db.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
       Toast.makeText(myContext,"I am in check db",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //SQLiteDatabase b = this.getReadableDatabase();
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
         InputStream myInput=null;
         OutputStream myOutput=null;
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        Log.d(TAG,"copy safe");
         myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            DB_PATH = myContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //Open the empty db as the output stream
             myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            Log.d(TAG,"input,output"+myInput+ " , "+ outFileName);
            Toast.makeText(myContext,"OutputStream is " + myOutput,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

                //Log.d(TAG, "loadUserData() email is " + buffer);
            }
            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            //Open the database
            //Toast.makeText(myContext,"start opening",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //SQLiteDatabase b = this.getReadableDatabase();
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            Log.d(TAG,"copied data path is: "+myDataBase.getMaximumSize());
            Toast.makeText(myContext,"finish opening",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }
        public Contacts getContact(int id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor;
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                   KEY_CODE,KEY_ABOUT,KEY_CONTENT,KEY_FILENAME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    //        Toast.makeText(myContext,"getting content "+cursor.getString(3),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //cursor=null;
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                Toast.makeText(myContext,"finish getting content",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //return new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
                  //  cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you get "SQLException"  when you call "openDataBase()" ?

Comment: As I understand at the first time,while the program check database, openDataBase give exception and it goat to catch section in checkDataBase method

Comment: Change DB_PATH = mycontext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/databases/";

Comment: Why not just use the SQLiteAssetHelper library? https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks for your answer, I think it works however I now have problem with my emulator Genymotion. Would you please explain the error occured in my code using SqliteOpenHelper class??